# Type Error when assigning requestAnimationFrame to object variable

Tags: javascript, typeerror, requestanimationframe

I have come across this strange `Type Error` that keeps occurring when I'm trying to create a local reference to `window.requestAnimationFrame`. The following works as expected and will log `Foo`:

```
var foo = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame || 
    function(fn){ setTimeout(fn, 1000 / 24); };

foo(function(){ console.log('Foo') });
```

When I tie in to a parent object, however, it does not work and throws a `Type Error`, which I have to say has me puzzled:

```
var bar = {};

bar.foo = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame || 
    function(fn){ setTimeout(fn, 1000 / 24); };

bar.foo(function(){ console.log('Bar.Foo') });
```

Even though the `window` or `window.requestAnimationFrame` are never `undefined`, calling them throws a type error when nested. However, when I compare both variables they are considered equals. Is there a reason for this? Is there a way tos tore a working reference to the correct implementation inside an object?

```js
document.body.innerHTML += 'About to call Foo: <br />';
try {
 var foo = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame || 
  function(fn){ setTimeout(fn, 1000 / 24); };
  
 foo(function(){ document.body.innerHTML += '<i>Foo</i><br />'; });
} catch(e){
 document.body.innerHTML += '<i> &gt;&gt;&gt; Error thrown when calling Foo.</i><br />';
}

document.body.innerHTML += 'About to call Bar.Foo: <br />';
try {
 var bar = {};
 bar.foo = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame || 
  function(fn){ setTimeout(fn, 1000 / 24); };
 bar.foo(function(){ document.body.innerHTML += '<i>Bar.Foo</i><br />'; });
} catch(e){
 document.body.innerHTML += '<i> &gt;&gt;&gt; Error thrown when calling Bar.Foo.</i><br />';
}

document.body.innerHTML += foo === bar.foo
  ? '<strong>Foo and Bar.Foo are considered the same</strong><br />'
  : '<strong>Foo and Bar.Foo are NOT considered the same</strong><br />';
```

```css
body { 
  font-family: Monaco, 'Courier MS', Coureire, mono-space;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `requestAnimationFrame` is part of the DOM API, it's not a JavaScript object so it's hard to be *sure* of why it fails. Keep in mind that:

- functions in JavaScript are dispatched with `this` set to the caller object, in your case that object is `bar` which doesn't have all the properties `window` has.
- The *default* object JavaScript functions are dispatched with is `window` - so calling `window.alert` and `alert` is the same thing (Except in strict mode).

So, it's entirely possible behind the scenes it uses `this` somewhere. Then again, it's a "Host Object" so all bets are off.

Here is similar "plain" JS code with the same behavior.

```js
window.msg = "Hello";

function foo(){
    if(this !== window) throw new TypeError("Illegal Invocation");   
    alert(this.msg);
}

foo(); // alerts hello, `this` is window
window.foo(); // alerts hello
var bar = {};
bar.foo = foo;
bar.foo(); // typeerror
```

A workaround would be to wrap it in an anonymous function or use `bind`.

Comment: To further prove this point: Supplying the correct value for `this` using `bar.foo.call(window, …)` works.

Comment: Cool, I was unaware that it was tied so closely to the `window` and the `Type Error` being thrown wasn't very descriptive.

Comment: @somethinghere that's true, it's equally annoying with `var log = console.log; log("HI");` and with `var resolve = Promise.resolve; resolve(5);`. Maybe I'll ping some peopel about it.

Comment: I think given that it's specified on the `Window` interface, expecting a `window` as its `this` value is quite reasonable.

Comment: @Bergi [not really, no](http://w3c.github.io/animation-timing/) but it's a liberty many interfaces take.

Comment: [Related Gecko bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=989619) (here: for `console`). I think the way the spec is written, this behavior is *standard*, as sad as that is.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: It seems sensible to me that rAF, just like `setTimeout`, does take a window (browsing context) as its context to know which queue to schedule the callback in. There's not necessarily a single one per realm :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var bar = {};

bar.foo = (window.requestAnimationFrame && window.requestAnimationFrame.bind(window)) || 
    (window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame && window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame.bind(window)) || 
    (window.mozRequestAnimationFrame && window.mozRequestAnimationFrame.bind(window)) || 
    (window.msRequestAnimationFrame && window.msRequestAnimationFrame.bind(window)) || 
    function(fn){ setTimeout(fn, 1000 / 24); };

bar.foo(function(){ console.log('Bar.Foo') });
```

this sets `this` for the *requestAnimation to the window object

as per comment by @poke

```
var bar = {};

bar.foo = (window.requestAnimationFrame || 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame || 
    function(fn){ setTimeout(fn, 1000 / 24); }).bind(window);

bar.foo(function(){ console.log('Bar.Foo') });
```

Comment: You don’t need to use this many conditionals, you can just bind the final result of `bar.foo`. It doesn’t harm the custom function (using the timeout) to run bound to `window`.

Comment: @JaromandaX I think you misunderstood what he meant - I think he meant you only need to do it _once_, but only _after_ selecting the correct animationFrame function. So... `bar.foo = (window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(fn){ setTimeout(fn, 1000 / 24); }); bar.foo = bar.foo.bind(window)`, where you only `bind` once, but bind to whatever is there.

Comment: which is what the second version does, in one command rather than two :D